# Orbeon xforms database service to call function or procedure

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I have Orbeon FormBuilder deloyed on Weblogic with Weblogic database connection pools configured.  I would like to use an Orbeon database service/action to call/invoke an Oracle procedure or function.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

I have tried call, execute and curly braces {} in the database service.  The closest I have come is:

```
2011-02-01 09:16:31,142 ERROR SQLProcessor  - PreparedStatement:
var result varchar2
call cv_ebf_mail_add_record_fn( ? , ? ,  ? ) into :result
2011-02-01 09:16:31,149 INFO  DatabaseContext  - Rolling back JDBC connection for datasource: jdbc/orbeontoolkitDS.
2011-02-01 09:16:31,150 ERROR ProcessorService  - Exception at
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 4
```

All other attempts have resulted in harsher errors.  Any help would be appreciated or confirmation Orbeon cannot call functions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will will work, but you could try:

```
select cv_ebf_mail_add_record_fn( ? , ? ,  ? ) from dual
```

And then getting the result as if a table with one column (and in this case one row) was returned.

Comment: Doesn't work because function eventually calls a proc that performs DML operations, which is illegal (and ill-advised) from dual. I'd like to speak to you about adding this as a feature.  I los your email address, can you send me a meeting invite?

Comment: Sure, feel free to email me; avernet(AT)orbeon.com.